# Nothing to publish, octree is empty

Tags: c++, ros, point-clouds

I am a publishing a PointCloud (Type: sensor_msgs/PointCloud2) in topic pc_pub. I have remapped "cloud_in" topic to the according pointcloud topic and the fixed frame in the launch file corresponds to the fixed frame in rviz (map) . Running ran "rostopic echo pc_pub" verifies that the pointcloud is indeed being published to this topic and octomap_server is Subscribing into the topic too. However, "Nothing to publish, octree is empty" appears.
What could the problem be?

```
<!-- fixed map frame (set to 'map' if SLAM or localization running!) -->
<param name="frame_id" type="string" value="map" />

<!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
<param name="sensor_model/max_range" value="100.0" />

<!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
<remap from="cloud_in" to="/pc_pub" />
```

Comment: Is error message appearing at the startup only and program keeps working, or your gazebo crashes after the error message?

Comment: If you are following a tutorial, sharing it also may help.

Comment: It appears only at startup. I am made a Pointcloud Publisher following the instructions from http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros. I also checked that all the including ports are in  LISTENING status.

Comment: If your program keeps working properly after the error message, there is nothing to worry about. Most likely pointcloud message is not arriving early enough at the startup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In addition, by "running rosrun rviz rviz" with fixed frame map, I am getting warning "No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist". I am missing something there?

Comment: Error message is saying there is no frame called "map". Check which of your custom nodes or built-in packages supposed to publish map frame. Also, you can view tf frames as shown here: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_tools

Comment: Thank you. Can you make a short post so i can accept and upvote it. (By running "rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map base_link 50" also solved the aformentioned map frame problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If error message is only showing up at the startup and program continues to work properly afterwards, there is nothing to worry about. Most likely first pointcloud message is not arriving early enough at the startup, since it is not a lightweight message type.
However, if your ros/gazebo crashes after the error message, your setup needs to be examined further to find the cause.

About "Fixed Frame [map] does not exist" message, error message is saying that there is not a frame called "map". Check which of your custom nodes or built-in packages supposed to publish map frame. Also, you can view tf frames as shown here: wiki.ros.org/tf2_tools.